# Generate a html tree with php from a specific user using mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I would like to generate a tree from the following tables:
TBLPROJECTS Id Name mainprojectid (this is the parentid, this is 0 by default unless it is part of another project)

TBLUSERPROJECTS userprojectid userid projectid

TBLUSERS id name

I now have the following code:

```
require_once 'php/connectie.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION['klantid'])){
    $klantid = $_SESSION['klantid'];
    function categoryParentChildTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $category_tree_array = '') {
        global $connectie;
        global $klantid;
        $parent = $connectie->real_escape_string($parent);
        if (!is_array($category_tree_array))
            $category_tree_array = array();

        $sqlCategory = "SELECT id,name,mainprojectid FROM projects WHERE mainprojectid = $parent ORDER BY id ASC";
        $resCategory=$connectie->query($sqlCategory);

        if ($resCategory->num_rows > 0) {
            while($rowCategories = $resCategory->fetch_assoc()) {
                $category_tree_array[] = array("id" => $rowCategories['id'], "name" => $spacing . $rowCategories['name']);
                $category_tree_array = categoryParentChildTree($rowCategories['id'], '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$spacing . '-&nbsp;', $category_tree_array);
            }
        }
        return $category_tree_array;
    }

    $categoryList = categoryParentChildTree();
    foreach($categoryList as $key => $value){
        $name= $value['name'];
        $id= $value['id'];
        echo ' 
            <form action="" method="post">
                <p> '.$name.' <button  value="'.$id.'" name="addproject"  type="submit">+</button>  <button value="'.$id.'" name="checkproject" type="submit">Tijdregistratie</button>  </p>
            </form>  <br> ';
    }}
```

This generates a tree of all the projects but not from one specific user. When I try this SQL:

```
SELECT id,name,mainprojectid FROM userproject JOIN projects ON projects.id = userproject.project_id WHERE user_id = 3
```

it just goes into an infinite loop... So I'm kinda stuck now.

Comment: What happens if you run that same query directly on your database?

Comment: I get the same result as the first query.

Answer (score 0):

try a left join

```
SELECT id,name,mainprojectid FROM userproject left JOIN projects ON   projects.id = userproject.project_id WHERE user_id = 3
```

Comment: It still goas into an infinite loop.Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40960 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\projecten.php on line 153

Comment: how many records are your dealing with? because it does not seem like an infinite loop more like too many records returned. Try "select top 100 " <rest of sql> see if you get any returns.

Comment: I only have 3 records xD